# TextAutoComplete съезжает при скролле

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, autocomplete, angular

Привет, пришел на новый проект, используется angular 1.3. В одном модальном окне с настройками есть textAutoComplete (его я не нашел). 
При скролле - если эта подсказка не выбрана, она скроллится вниз вместе с содержимым документа, словно у неё `position: fixed`, выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От инспектора кода оно убегает, и как это найти и исправить не очень представляю. Можно при скролле отлавливать эту подсказку, и через колбек ее скрывать. Но для этого мне нужно как то её найти.

А что это - директива или отдельная библа, я так и не смог найти.

Если подскажете, в какую сторону смотреть, было бы уже неплохо.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону кода. Откройте страницу в инспекторе, посмотрете исходный код элемента, попробуйте найти его в коде проекта через поиск по файлам. Если вы имея код на руках не можете разобраться, то здесь вам вряд ли кто поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Дело было в том, что браузерный autocomplete(да, это был он, проверил в лисе - там все окей). Он по какой-то причине лагает. В данный момент ищу решение.

[Вот тот же баг, и способы его решения.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646805/wrong-input-autocompletion-position-on-scroll-chrome) Как раз отсюда и попытаюсь найти выход.